# How to convert result into string from int SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psGetReprintNLot]
    @codOrder VARCHAR(15)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        codPackedBatch AS codPackedBatch
    FROM            
        PackedOrder 
    INNER JOIN
        [Order] ON PackedOrder.codOrder = [Order].codOrder
    WHERE
        (PackedOrder.codOrder = @codOrder OR @codOrder IS NULL)
        AND RIGHT([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch, 1) <> 8 
    ORDER BY
        codPackedBatch ASC

    IF @@Error <> 0 
        RETURN -1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Problem:

I have a `@codOrder` with a string = 'M18111301'.

```
Exec [psGetReprintNLot] 'M18111301'
```

When I 'm trying to execute the stored procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure psGetReprintNLot, Line 47
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'M18111301' to data type int.

But when I am trying to execute:

```
Exec [psGetReprintNLot] '721718346'
```

it's working as expected. How can I get values if I am entering string?

If I try like this below: I am getting correct result for 'M' but not for normal '72...46'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psGetReprintNLot]
    @codOrder VARCHAR(15)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SELECT DISTINCT codPackedBatch as codPackedBatch
    --FROM PackedOrder 
    --INNER JOIN [Order] ON PackedOrder.codOrder = [Order].codOrder
    --WHERE (PackedOrder.codOrder = @codOrder or @codOrder IS NULL)
    --AND Right([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch,1) <> 8 order by codPackedBatch Asc                    
    SELECT DISTINCT codPackedBatch AS codPackedBatch
    FROM PackedOrder 
    WHERE (PackedOrder.codPackedOrder = @codOrder OR @codOrder IS NULL) 
      AND RIGHT([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch, 1) <> 8 
    ORDER BY codPackedBatch ASC

    IF @@Error <> 0 
        RETURN -1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: @codOrder starts with a letter M; how would you like to convert that to an INT? Drop it? change it to 13 (it's the 13th lettter of the alphabet), change it to a 77 (its the ascii code for M)? What? You have to decide what to so with the non numerical chars; the database can't decide for you!

Comment: Try executing: **exec [psGetReprintNLot] 'M18111301'** instead of, **exec [psGetReprintNLot] '721718346'**. Probably you will not work as expected.

Comment: @BishalGautam Great....

Comment: probably "codOrder" column in table "Order"/"PackedOrder" is of type int.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes because your `PackedOrder.codOrder` column has an INT datatype and you're comparing it to a varchar:

```
PackedOrder.codOrder = @codOrder
```

When the string @codOrder contains only numerics, SQLServer will successfully convert @codOrder's contents to an INT and then run the query

When your @codOrder contains alpha characters too, SQLServer will fail to convert it to an int and give this error

SQLServer won't attempt to convert all your table data to varchar in order to perform a string:string comparison because converting table data implicitly to match a variable like this is wasteful of resources and in most cases data conversions mean indexes cannot be used. All in it means that converting millions of rows to match the data type of one variable has terrible performance implciations and shouldn't be done

If you really want to do that conversion explicitly you can CAST() your table column to a varchar, but seeinf as the table column is an INT, it will never contain `M18111301` anyway so converting a million INTs to varchar and then searching them for an alphanumeric is a 100% pointless exercise.

You'd be better off changing your procedure so it takes an INT typed @codOrder instead, and stop trying to feed alphanumeric data into it

Alternatively, as per the comment under the question, if `M18111301` is in some way related to the data in the table (for example the table does contain `18111301`, so you should chop the M off) then modify the variable so it matches something in the table, and do your search

---

In response to your edit, and my comment below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psGetReprintNLot]
    @codOrder VARCHAR(15)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @codOrder LIKE 'M%'
    SELECT DISTINCT codPackedBatch AS codPackedBatch
    FROM PackedOrder 
    WHERE (PackedOrder.codPackedOrder = @codOrder OR @codOrder IS NULL) 
      AND RIGHT([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch, 1) <> 8 
    ORDER BY codPackedBatch ASC
  ELSE
    SELECT DISTINCT codPackedBatch as codPackedBatch
    FROM PackedOrder 
    INNER JOIN [Order] ON PackedOrder.codOrder = [Order].codOrder
    WHERE (PackedOrder.codOrder = @codOrder or @codOrder IS NULL)
    AND Right([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch,1) <> 8 order by codPackedBatch Asc     
  END IF;

    IF @@Error <> 0 
        RETURN -1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

?

If you're expecting @codOrder values that have any alpha chars anywhere else, like `123TP456` then you can test with `LIKE '%[A-Z]%'`

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. But I need some result which are present in both codOrder or Codpackedorder. So i need 'M'.

Comment: If I try like this:

Comment: So, you mean the rule is: if you're passing in a @codOrder that has an M at the start, then it's a `PackedOrder.codPackedOrder`, and if the input has no M at the start, then it's a `PackedOrder.codOrder` ? Why not use an IF, then? `IF @codOrder LIKE 'M%' THEN (run one query) ELSE (run the other query) END`

Answer (score 0):

Probably You are looking for this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[psGetReprintNLot]
    @codOrder VARCHAR(15)   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT codPackedBatch as codPackedBatch
    FROM PackedOrder 
    INNER JOIN [Order] ON PackedOrder.codOrder = [Order].codOrder
    WHERE (@codOrder IS NULL or @codOrder = case when isnumeric(@codOrder) then PackedOrder.codOrder else PackedOrder.codPackedOrder end)
    AND Right([PackedOrder].codPackedBatch,1) <> 8 order by codPackedBatch Asc      

   IF @@Error <> 0 
        RETURN -1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```